# Seeking ArcGIS Pro equivalent to Model Iteration Properties

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-pro, iteration

I am trying to make the transfer from ArcMap to ArcGIS Pro. ArcMap ModelBuilder properties had an Interation tab that would allow you to run the model multiple times with different stopping criteria. I am not finding the equivalent in ArcGIS Pro, and I am assuming my models need to reconfigured to use for, while, stop etc.

Is that the case?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think those techniques for looping in ArcMap are under used and essentially replaced by the iterator.

You are correct in stating there is no equivalent set of options in ArcGIS Pro.

You could use the FOR iterator if you wanted your model to loop X number of times. ArcGIS Pro offers more utility tools to test and control processing order.

So the bulk of your model logic should easily port over, just the looping aspect needs rebuilding. I would say if your are doing lots of loops within loops then Python would be much easier.